# how to merge a branch to a branch that changed a lot and were not merge for a couple years

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

Branches:

- *dev:* my main branch
- *experimental:* split from dev 4 years ago.
- *feature1:* split from experimental 6 months ago

Now I need feature from *feature1* but I don't need other features from experimental. How to move the commits from the *feature1* branch to *dev* but without merging it, cause there will be to much conflicts? There are ~400 commits in *feature1* experimental and ~3000 difference in *dev* and *experimental*.

Answer (score 2):

As always, let's start by visualizing the situation:

```
o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o (dev)
         \
          o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o (experimental)
                           \
                            A---B---C (feature1)
```

The easiest way to bring the changes from `feature1` into `dev` is to use the [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) command:

```sh
git switch dev
git cherry-pick A^..C
```

This will *apply* the range of commits between the parent of `A` (exclusive) and `C` (inclusive) on top of `dev`. In other words, commits `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---A'---B'---C' (dev)
         \
          o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o (experimental)
                           \
                            A---B---C (feature1)
```

Note that you're *still* going to have to resolve any conflicts between the changes contained in `A`, `B` and `C` and `dev`. However, it won't be as many as if you had tried to merge `feature1` to `dev`.